# Confusion about the proof that radical solvability has transitivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm reading Siegfried Bosch's *Algebra From the Viewpoint of Galois Theory*, which gives the following definition:

A finite field extension $L/K$ is said to be ***solvable by radicals*** if $L$ admits an extension field $E$ together with a chain of field extensions :
$$ K =: E_0 \subset E_1 \subset \cdots \subset E_m $$
such that in each case, $E_{i+1}$ is obtained from $E_i$ by adjoining an element of the
following type:

(1) a root of unity, or

(2) a zero of a polynomial of type $X^n − a \in E_i[X]$, where $\mathrm{char}(K) \nmid n$, or

(3) a zero of a polynomial of type $X^p − X − a \in E_i[X]$ for $p = \mathrm{char}(K) > 0$.

Then $L/K$ is necessarily separable.

Now I'm reading the proof of the following lemma:

*Given a chain of finite field extensions $K \subset L \subset M$, the extension $M/K$ is solvable (resp. solvable by radicals) if and only if $M/L$ and $L/K$ are solvable (resp. solvable by radicals).*

I am confused about the proof of the part "*If $M/L$ and $L/K$ root equations are solvable by radicals, then $M/K$ root equations are solvable by radicals*". The idea of this part of the proof is as follows:

*Choose an extension $L'/L$ such that $L'/K$ can be exhausted by a chain of field extensions as specified in the above definition. Then consider the composite field $L'M$ in an algebraic closure of $M$ and use the fact that $L'M/L'$ is solvable by radicals. It follows that $L'M/K$ is solvable by radicals and that the same is true for $M/K$.*

Where I get confused is why we get $L'M/K$ root solvable by radicals? I can't think of any reason.